# How do I install CoverArt Browser plugin on Arch Linux for Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

I am a Unix & Linux enthusiast and control freak who loves the freedom of Arch Linux, yet does not fully understand everything. Could somebody help me get this thing running? It is not on the AUR, so I tried setting it up myself:

## Attempt 1

```
cd $HOME/build && git clone https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser && cd coverart-browser && sh install.sh
```

### Results

```
installing languages to /usr/share/locale/
installing en_US
en_US.po:13: warning: header field 'Language-Team' still has the initial default value
Installing the glib schema (password needed)
```

## Attempt 2

I also tried putting the whole thing into

```
~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins
```

## Results

(after restarting Rhythmbox) This image illustrates to GUI result of both attempts.
[image]

## Notes

```
if info_given < info_needed:
  leave comment
```

Upstream URL:
https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser

Comment: Let's start with the basic `info_needed`: I presume the plugin didn't work (you didn't actually explicitly say that...). Have you restarted Rhythmbox, and did you get any errors at any step of the process?

Comment: @derobert `leave comment` function has been called. Requested `info_needed` has been added.

Comment: is the errored out plugin picture from Attempt 1 or 2? Anyway, I don't really have an answer (sorry), but seems like there must be a log of what went wrong somewhere. Maybe if you launch Rhythmbox from the console? I don't actually know how to get one from Rhythmbox. (I'd guess a missing dependency, but that's only a guess—I suspect a proper error log will make the solution apparent).